# What is the things on front of the Canon 600EX RT?

Tags: canon, flash, off-camera-flash, hotshoe-flash

There are two things on the front.

An hole with a metal rod in it [perhaps a connection for something]

A red piece of glass with something in it. [stupid guess says it's an charging indicator.]

What are these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking for information about something, it always is a good idea to do a quick research in the manual. [The 600EX-RT's manual shows on p. 6](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300007510/01/600ex-600ex-rt-c-en.pdf#page=8):

[image: Slightly edited and cut version from manual, p.6]

So my guess is that you mean the **external metering sensor** and the **optical transmission wireless sensor**, which both sit just above the **AF-assist beam emitter** (that would be my third guess).